# Add number to a variable in a formula until a maximum value is reached python

Tags: python, excel, calculation

I have the following problem -
I want to set up a python code which is adding a float value (e.g. 0.1) to a variable in a formula until a maximum value is reached.
I've got different values from an `Excel file`, so I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", encoding="latin1",dtype={"A": float, "G": float, "K": float, "V": float})

df["k"] = (df["A"] * df["V"] / 100 + df["G"] - df["K"]) / df["V"] * 100
while df["k"] < 15:
    df["k"] = (df["A"] * df["V"] / 100 + df["G"] - df["K"]) / df["V"] * 100
    df["A"] = df["A"] + 0.01

print([df])
```

When i try to execute the code i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xx\xx\x\pythonProject\Test x+1.py", line 10, in <module>
    while df["k"] < 15:
  File "C:\xx\xx\x\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Do you know why and how to fix this problem?

Sample:

1. V   A   G   K
2. 500 26,27   41,68   173,03 1000 26,27   41,68   304,38
3. 1500    26,27   41,68   435,73 2000 26,27   41,68   567,08
4. 2500    26,27   41,68   698,43 3000 26,27   41,68   829,78
5. 3500    26,27   41,68   961,13 4000 26,27   41,68   1092,48

Comment: did you try printing out what `df['k']` is before starting the loop? and during looping?

Comment: What does your df look like?

Comment: df['k'] is 0 in all cases and needs to be raised to the closest value possible to 15 (by adding 0.01 to A)

Comment: I will post a sample of my df in the bottom of my question

Comment: Yes thats right thats a a mistake i copied from testing other variations of the code -  i tried many things but all in all i want to print out the highest value for A which leads to a maximum value of 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that solves `A`:

Input data:

```
# df["k"] = (df["A"] * df["V"] / 100 + df["G"] - df["K"]) / df["V"] 
>>> df
      V      A      G        K             k
0   500  26.27  41.68   173.03  0.000000e+00
1  1000  26.27  41.68   304.38  0.000000e+00
2  1500  26.27  41.68   435.73  0.000000e+00
3  2000  26.27  41.68   567.08 -5.684342e-15
4  2500  26.27  41.68   698.43  0.000000e+00
5  3000  26.27  41.68   829.78  0.000000e+00
6  3500  26.27  41.68   961.13  0.000000e+00
7  4000  26.27  41.68  1092.48  0.000000e+00
```

```
def solve_A(sr):
    A = sr["A"]
    k = sr["k"]
    while k < 15:
        prev_A = A
        prev_k = k
        A += 0.1
        k = (A * sr["V"] / 100 + sr["G"] - sr["K"]) / sr["V"] * 100
    sr["A"] = prev_A
    sr["k"] = prev_k
    return sr

out = df.apply(solve_A, axis="columns")
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
        V      A      G        K     k
0   500.0  41.17  41.68   173.03  14.9
1  1000.0  41.17  41.68   304.38  14.9
2  1500.0  41.17  41.68   435.73  14.9
3  2000.0  41.17  41.68   567.08  14.9
4  2500.0  41.17  41.68   698.43  14.9
5  3000.0  41.17  41.68   829.78  14.9
6  3500.0  41.17  41.68   961.13  14.9
7  4000.0  41.17  41.68  1092.48  14.9
```

---

**Alternative**: don't use a loop, solve `A` directly.

Sample :

```
# df["k"] = (df["A"] * df["V"] / 100 + df["G"] - df["K"]) / df["V"] * 100
>>> df
    A   G   K   V          k
0  27  14  18  14  -1.571429  # OK
1  24  18  16  26  31.692308  # <- change A
2  13  18  19  24   8.833333  # OK
3  23  23  18  27  41.518519  # <- change A
4  22  13  15  23  13.304348  # OK
```

Express your equation in terms of A:

```
k = 15 - 0.1
A = (-100*G + 100*K + V*k)/V

# Compute A
>>> (-100*18 + 100*16 + 26*14.99)/26
7.297692307692308

# Check k
>>> (7.297692307692308 * 24 / 100 + 18 - 19) / 24 * 100
14.990000000000004
```

So:

```
mask = df.loc[df['k'] >= 15]

A = ((-100*df['G'] + 100*df['K'] + df['V']*14.99)/df['V'])

df.loc[mask, 'A'] = A.loc[mask]
df.loc[mask, 'k'] = 14.99
```

```
>>> df
           A   G   K   V          k
0  27.000000  14  18  14  -1.571429
1   7.297692  18  16  26  14.990000
2  13.000000  18  19  24   8.833333
3  -3.528519  23  18  27  14.990000
4  22.000000  13  15  23  13.304348
```

**Tips**: express `A` using `SymPy`

```
# pip install sympy
from sympy import symbols, solve, Eq

A, G, K, V, k = symbols('A G K V k')
expr = Eq((A * V / 100 + G - K) / V * 100, k)
```

```
>>> solve(expr, A)[0]
(-100*G + 100*K + V*k)/V
```

Comment: Thank you @Corralien, i will keep this solution in mind, but in this case i will need the loop because in the later use i will need to add an other limitation which needs to be met

Comment: @user16429309. I updated my answer according to your need.